# Python: get a checkbox - the easiest way

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

or perhaps the lazy way..

I'm looking for a python module that has some build-in GUI methods to get quick user inputs - a very common programming case. Has to work on windows 7

**My ideal case**

```
import magicGUImodule
listOfOptions = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
choosenOptions = magicGUImodule.getChecklist(listOfOptions, 
                            selectMultiple=True, cancelButton=True)
```

It's kinda like `raw_input` but with a GUI. There must be something out there since this is a common programming task.

---

### UPDATE

@alecxe it is not to be rude that I unchecked your answer as the solution to my problem. I still want to be able to use **my ideal case** in whatever script I'm working on and your answer gets me half the way.

I thought that I could implement @alecxe's solution easily into a module, but it's not that simple (for me)..

Here is my module so far:

```
# This serve as a module to get user input - the easy way!
# Some GUI selection
#from Tkinter import *
import Tkinter

master = Tkinter.Tk()
input = None
listbox = None

def chooseFromList(list, windowTitle="Choose from list", buttonText="Submit", selectMultiple=False, w=150, h=30):
    global listbox
    listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(master, selectmode=MULTIPLE if selectMultiple else SINGLE, width=w, height=h)
    listbox.master.title(windowTitle)
    for option in list:
        listbox.insert(0, option)
    listbox.pack()
    #listbox.selection_set(1)
    b = Tkinter.Button(master, command=callback(listbox), text=buttonText)
    b.pack()
    mainloop()

def callback(listbox):
    global listbox
    setInput(listbox.selection_get())
    master.destroy()    

def setInput(var):
    global input
    input = var

def getInput():
    global input
    return input
```

And here is my script

```
import GetUserInput
listOfOptions = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
choice = GetUserInput.chooseFromList(listOfOptions)
print choice.getInput()
```

But I just get the error

`can't invoke "listbox" command: application has been destroyed`

Have tried a lot of different options that I though would solve the case (like using global variable) - but without any luck.

### UPDATE 2

@blablatros gave me exactly the solution that I was looking for.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

[Easygui](http://easygui.sourceforge.net/) module is **exactly** what you need:

```
import easygui as eg

question = "This is your question"
title = "This is your window title"
listOfOptions = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]

choice = eg.multchoicebox(question , title, listOfOptions)
```

`choice` will return a list of selected answers.

Use `multchoicebox` for multiple choice question, or `choicebox` for a single choice.

Comment: You hit it spot on! I knew I'm not the only lazy python programmer out there.. Thank you very much

Comment: Lazy programmers rejoice! Glad I could help.

Comment: I know you guys were rejoicing over this a couple years back, but I just sang my own praises.  Finally, something quick and simple!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a simple example using `Tkinter` (instead of checkboxes `listbox` with multiple selection is used):

```
from Tkinter import *


def callback():
    print listbox.selection_get()
    master.destroy()


master = Tk()

listbox = Listbox(master, selectmode=MULTIPLE)
for option in ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]:
    listbox.insert(0, option)
listbox.pack()

b = Button(master, command=callback, text="Submit")
b.pack()

mainloop()
```

UPDATE:

`GetUserInput.py`:

```
from Tkinter import *


class GetUserInput(object):
    selection = None

    def __init__(self, options, multiple):
        self.master = Tk()

        self.master.title("Choose from list")

        self.listbox = Listbox(self.master, selectmode=MULTIPLE if multiple else SINGLE, width=150, height=30)
        for option in options:
            self.listbox.insert(0, option)
        self.listbox.pack()

        b = Button(self.master, command=self.callback, text="Submit")
        b.pack()

        self.master.mainloop()

    def callback(self):
        self.selection = self.listbox.selection_get()
        self.master.destroy()

    def getInput(self):
        return self.selection
```

main script:

```
from GetUserInput import GetUserInput

listOfOptions = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
print GetUserInput(listOfOptions, True).getInput()
```

Hope that helps.

Comment: I could just wrap it up in function in a personal python module (magicGUImodule) - it would basically just call your code :)

Comment: You are welcome, sure. I bet it would be as simple in any python gui tool like `wx` or `qt`.

Comment: How do I dig the MULTIPLE parameter from Tkinter? I want to create a list like: mode =  [SelectMode.SINGLE, SelectMode.MULTIPLE] // listbox = Listbox(master, selectmode=mode[True], width=w, height=h)

Comment: I had some small OOP problems creating the module. So had to reopen the question.. sorry for that.

Comment: Thank you VERY much! - how would you go about avoiding global variables?

Comment: You are welcome. I've updated the answer - now looks definitely better.

Comment: I actually like the first one, but only because it would be possible to implement other easy-to-call-predefined methods like `GetUserInput.getString(messageText="Please type in the options you would like to add to the list")`

Comment: Well, the last solution uses class variables instead of global per-script variables and it's more pythonic and clean. For other easy-call-predefined methods just use this class as a template. Hope that helps.

Answer (score 4):

### Listbox

```
import Tkinter

def callback(master, listbox, selection):
    selection[:] = [listbox.get(i) for i in map(int, listbox.curselection())]
    master.destroy()

def chooseFromList(options, windowTitle="Choose from list", buttonText="Submit", selectMultiple=False, w=150, h=30):
    master = Tkinter.Tk()
    master.title(windowTitle)
    listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(master, selectmode=Tkinter.MULTIPLE if selectMultiple else Tkinter.SINGLE, width=w, height=h)
    for option in options:
        listbox.insert(Tkinter.END, option)
    listbox.pack()
    selection = []
    Tkinter.Button(master, command=lambda: callback(master, listbox, selection), text=buttonText).pack()
    master.mainloop()
    return selection
```

### Checkbutton + Radiobutton

Use Checkbutton for multiple options, Radiobutton for single option.

```
def chooseFromList(options, windowTitle="Choose from list", buttonText="Submit", selectMultiple=False, w=150, h=30):
    master = Tkinter.Tk()
    master.title(windowTitle)

    variables = []
    if selectMultiple:
        for option in options:
            v = Tkinter.StringVar()
            variables.append(v)
            Tkinter.Checkbutton(text=option, variable=v, onvalue=option, offvalue='').pack()
    else:
        v = Tkinter.StringVar()
        variables.append(v)
        for option in options:
            Tkinter.Radiobutton(text=option, variable=v, value=option).pack()

    Tkinter.Button(master, command=master.destroy, text=buttonText).pack()
    master.mainloop()
    return [v.get() for v in variables if v.get()]
```

Answer (score 4):

I've iterated over @alecxe's answer, using OOP to manage the GUI life time in a more robust way :

### The GUI elem

```
# This serve as a module to get user input - the easy way!
# Some GUI selection
import Tkinter

default_kwargs = { 
                  'selectmode'  : "single"          ,
                  'width'       : "150"             ,
                  'height'      : "30"              ,
                  'title'       : "Choose from list",
                  'buttonText'  : "Submit"  
}



class easyListBox:

    def __init__(self, options_list, **kwargs) :

        #options
        opt = default_kwargs #default options
        opt.update(kwargs) #overrides default if existant

        #Return value
        self.selected = 0;

        # GUI master object (life-time component)
        self.master = Tkinter.Tk()

        # Checklist with options
        listbox_options = { key: opt[key] for key in opt if key in['selectmode','width','height'] } #options slice for GUI
        self.listbox = Tkinter.Listbox(self.master, listbox_options)
        self.listbox.master.title(opt['title'])

        #Options to be checked
        for option in options_list:
            self.listbox.insert(0,option)
        self.listbox.pack()

        # Submit callback
        self.OKbutton = Tkinter.Button(self.master, command=self.OKaction, text=opt['buttonText'] )
        self.OKbutton.pack()

        #Main loop
        self.master.mainloop()

    # Action to be done when the user press submit
    def OKaction(self):
        self.selected =  self.listbox.selection_get()
        self.master.destroy() 

    # Return the selection
    def getInput(self):
        return self.selected
```

### The parent script

```
#import GetUserInput
import GUI as GetUserInput

listOfOptions = ["option 1", "option 2", "option 3"]
GUI_options = {'title' : "Custom title", 'selectmode' : 'multiple' }
#choice = GetUserInput.chooseFromList(listOfOptions)
elb = GetUserInput.easyListBox(listOfOptions, **GUI_options)
print elb.getInput()
```

I've added some default parameters kwargs in order to deal with variable parameters.

PS : I'm using Python 2.7, so some values had to be adjusted (ex MULTIPLE -> 'multiple')

Answer (score 1):

Well, you're not going to get something quite *that* quick, almost no matter where you look I don't think. Typically, you'll need at least need enough boilerplate to create a top-level window and/or widget to layout the input widgets you actually care about within.

Python has great bindings for both GTK2 and Qt (PyQt, use 4.X for now), both extremely high quality cross-platform GUI toolkits that are easy to get started with. There are others, wxWidgets being another prominent one, but the rest (including the builtin IMO) are rather outdated.

Answer (score 1):

**Tkinter** is built inside Python, has checkboxes pretty much in the form that you state above, and is much more straightforward than most other GUI modules. Please find a good tutorial (although needs some refreshing) [here](http://www.tkdocs.com/tutorial/). Official docs are [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/tkinter.html).

Answer (score 1):

From here you may get exact answer. Just click here http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2013/02/27/wxpython-adding-checkboxes-to-objectlistview/